# Oracle Query to Join Two Tables based on Conditions & Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have table in below format,

**Table 1**

| Bank | Category | Month_Year | Loan_Type | Outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Home | 10 |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Land | 50 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Home | 30 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Car | 40 |

**Table 2**

| Bank | Loan_Type |
| --- | --- |
| SI | Home |
| SI | Land |
| SI | Car |
| SI | Jewel |
| SI | Education |

I would like to convert the table A and B in to below format using join/query. The data(all rows) from the table-2 should get added based of the Category and Month_Year.

| BANK | Category | Month_Year | Loan_Type | Outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Home | 10 |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Land | 50 |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Car | 0 |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Jewel | 0 |
| SI | R1 | JAN-21 | Education | 0 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Home | 30 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Land | 0 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Car | 0 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Jewel | 0 |
| SI | R2 | FEB-21 | Education | 0 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Home | 0 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Land | 0 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Car | 40 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Jewel | 0 |
| SI | R2 | MAR-21 | Education | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Principally a `CROSS JOIN` needed among the tables after `Category` and `Month_Year` columns are distinctly selected, and `Outstanding` column is added in the main query as zero for non-matching values, otherwise returning values of it such as

```sql
SELECT t2.Bank, t2.Category, t2.Month_Year, t2.Loan_Type, 
       NVL(t1.Outstanding,0) AS Outstanding
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Category, Month_Year FROM table1) 
         CROSS JOIN table2) t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.Category = t1.Category
   AND t2.Month_Year = t1.Month_Year
   AND t2.Loan_Type = t1.Loan_Type
 ORDER BY t2.Category, t2.Month_Year, t1.Outstanding NULLS LAST
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dae23dd0a7f5531ec3d92758db55f86c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all items needed and left join Table1. For example

```
select items.Bank, items.Category, items.Month_Year, items.Loan_Type, coalesce(t1.Outstanding, 0) Outstanding
from (
    select t2.Bank, t2.Loan_Type, my.Month_Year,  cat.Category
    from (select distinct Month_Year
          from Table1) my
    cross join (select distinct Category
          from Table1) cat
    cross join Table2 t2
    ) items
left join Table1 t1 on items.Bank = t1.Bank and items.Loan_Type = t1.Loan_Type and items.Month_Year = t1.Month_Year and items.Category = t1.Category;
```

If there exists a table `Categories` replace it instead of derived categories in the query. You may also wish to generate a set of Month_Year from prameters or use a calendar table.